How to reenable Developer Options
I have a Nokia C32, Android 13.
I was using Developer Options on my phone, then after a while I could not locate the Developer Options in the settings.
After missing the Developer Options, I opted to click on Build Tools to see if I can reenable them to no avail. I tried some to including https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205856/re-enabling-developer-options and https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205856/re-enabling-developer-options, to no avail.I have also tried clearing the Settings App Storage & Cache.

The issue was resolved via a security update.
